# Responsive images in email

Tags: css, image, email, responsive-design, responsive-emails

I'm wanting to serve an image to mobile devices and different image to desktop devices in an email. `display: none` works well for everything but Outlook and Gmail. The image has a button on it, but on mobile, the text in the button gets too small. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
       img {content: url(http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/17000000/Nature-s-jewerly-love-you-natures-seasons-17036569-500-500.jpg)}
    }
</style>
<body>
    <img img src="http://data.whicdn.com/images/28179582/Nature-Photography-Rain-520x520_large.jpg" width="500" height="500">
</body>
```

iPhone and Android can handle `content`, which for me are the only mobile devices I have to worry about. They serve the image that I want, and the other desktop devices stay with the original image.

Answer (score 1):

Good to see that you found a solution that works for you. Should you or anyone else need `display: none` for mail clients in the future: for Outlook it's `mso-hide: all` and Gmail should work with `display: none` as long as it's in an inline style attribute, or `height: 0; width: 0; overflow: hidden;`

Comment: Interesting. I was just going off of this round up https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/b/ that said `display: none` wasn't possible for gmail.